# Fourier transform of a generalized function on the plane

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, mp.mathematical-physics, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, schrodinger-operators

> Is there an explicit formula for the Fourier transform of the generalized function of 2 variables
>   $$\frac{1}{x+y^2+i0}?$$

Remark. **Equivalent question:** consider the Schroedinger equation one the line
$$i\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\Psi(x,t)=\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}\Psi(x,t).$$

> Find the kernel $K(x,t)$ such that for $t>0$
>   $$\Psi(x,t)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty K(x-y,t)\Psi(x,0)dy.$$

Comment: The answer to the second question is the standard free particle particle propagator from quantum mechanics: $K(x,t) = (C_1/t^a) e^{iC_2 x^2/t}$ (exercise: fix the right constants $a, C_1, C_2$). $K(x,t)$ is not exactly the Fourier transform from the first question, they are related, as you say. I don't know if that's enough for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Fourier transform vanishes for $u>0$, for $u<0$ instead
$$
I(u,v)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx\int_{-\infty}^\infty dy\,\frac{e^{\mathrm{i}(ux+vy)}}{x+y^2+\mathrm{i}0^+}$$
$$\qquad\qquad=-ie^{i\pi/4}\sqrt{\pi }(- u)^{-1/2}\exp\left({\frac{i v^2}{4 u}}\right)\;\;\text{for}\;\; u<0. 
$$
For $u=0$ there is a delta function, $I(0,v)=-i\pi\delta(|v|)$. Note that
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty I(u,v)\,dv=\begin{cases}
0&\text{if}\;\;u>0,\\
-\pi i&\text{if}\;\;u=0,\\
-2\pi i&\text{if}\;\;u<0.
\end{cases}$$

Comment: So maybe the truly correct answer involves $\delta\otimes\delta$, in two variables, rather than the potentially misleading pointwise assertion ... which, yes, certainly does convey the spirit of the outcome... :)

Comment: @paulgarrett -- a term $\delta\otimes\delta$ would produce a delta function in $\int I(u,v)\,dv$, which is not what I find from a direct calculation of this integral.

Comment: Hm. Well, if there is a delta in one variable when the first variable is $0$, I don't know how else to interpret it, myself...

Answer (score 1):

The Fourier transform for $1/(x+y^2+\mathrm{i}\epsilon), \epsilon\in\mathbb{R}$ is formally compute as 
\begin{align}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}\frac{e^{2\pi\mathrm{i}(ux+vy)}}{x+y^2+\mathrm{i}\epsilon}\,dx\,dy&=\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-2\pi\mathrm{i}(uy^2-vy)}\,dy\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{e^{2\pi\mathrm{i}ux}}{x+\mathrm{i}\epsilon}\,dx\\
&=\frac{\mathrm{i}e^{\frac{\pi\mathrm{i}v^2}{2u}}}{\sqrt{{2\mathrm{i}u}}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{x\sin(2\pi ux)-\epsilon\cos(2\pi ux)}{x^2+\epsilon^2}\,dx\quad(u\neq 0 )\\
&=\frac{\mathrm{i}e^{\frac{\pi\mathrm{i}v^2}{2u}}}{\sqrt{{2\mathrm{i}u}}}\left(\pi{\rm sign}(u)-\pi+o_{u,\epsilon}(1)\right)= \frac{\pi\mathrm{i}e^{\frac{\pi\mathrm{i}v^2}{2u}}}{\sqrt{{2\mathrm{i}u}}}({\rm sign}(u)-1).~as~\epsilon \rightarrow 0. 
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Chanced on this and after much rumination I have decided to point out the following flaws in the postings.
Firstly, I assume that when you write $$\frac 1 {x+y^2+i0}$$ you mean a  limit of the function $$\frac 1 {x+y^2+i\epsilon}$$ as $\epsilon$ goes to zero.  In fact, since the value of the limit depends on whether it  is taken over positive or negative values, you probably mean $$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0+}\frac 1 {x+y^2+i\epsilon}.$$

However, the expression $\frac 1 {x+y^2}$ can also be regarded as a distribution in a natural way which is related to the concept of the  principal value of a function at a singularity.  This is due to the fact that $\log|x+y^2|$ is locally integrable and so can be interpreted as a distribution. We can define the above expression simply to be $D_x \log|x+y^2|$ (distributional  derivative).

The crucial point is that despite the trap set by the notation,
these two distributions are distinct--they differ by a delta like function supported on the singular set $x+y^2=0$ and of course this part is crucial in physical applications.

Now there is school of thought  on this site that believes that one solves research problems of this type simply  by bashing something into a computer.  Since it is no skin off my nose, I can only wish them good luck in their enterprise but feel obliged to point out that they are missing the (in my opinion crucial) term in the FT which arises from the singular part.

I might add that there is nothing formal in the approach sketched here--the details  can be made perfectly rigorous using simple elementary methods at the level of freshman analysis.  These tools were worked out in the 50´s of the previous century.

Comment: the calculation in my answer was for $u\neq 0$, I do think that is complete without delta functions; I added the case $u=0$, where a delta function of $|v|$ appears.